# onActivityResult is not calling after taking camera picture

Tags: android, bitmap, android-camera, onactivityresult

I am doing an android app, in which I have a functionality that, I need to open camera and take a picture. After taking picture onActivityResult is not called. my screen remains only in camera state.

My code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
File mediaFile = new File(
         MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI.getPath());
Uri imageUri = Uri.fromFile(mediaFile);
         intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, imageUri);
         startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
```

**onActivityResult code**

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (data != null && !data.toString().equalsIgnoreCase("Intent {  }"))
        switch (requestCode) {
        case 1:
            Log.i("StartUpActivity", "Photo Captured");
             Uri uri = data.getData();
             String imgPath = getRealPathFromURI(uri);
            bitmap = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
            MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(),
                    bitmap, null, null);
            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
            img1.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
}
}
```

Comment: make the `super.onActivityResult()` the last instruction on your `onActivityResult()` overrided method.
refer this guide of android to check it : http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html
Try to add some log to verify if the onActivityResult is really called or not

Comment: I have answered this question before
take a look :
http://stackoverflow.com/a/30266776/1531683

Answer (score 0):

`onActivityResult` is probably called, but the statements inside your `if` statement and `switch/case` statements are not being executed, because they are never reached.

The code below includes two methods `takePhoto` and `onActivityResult`, is very short and works perfectly. Take a look at it, it probably will help you!

```
public void takePhoto(View v) {
    Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST);
  }

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == 1) {
      photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
      imageView.setImageBitmap(photo);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can run your application in debug mode, after putting a breakpoint in **`onActivityResult`** method,
if it's stopping there after getting from the Camera then it's being called successfully.

and you could just change the **`if`** statement you're using making your code like this:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (data != null && resultCode = RESULT_OK)
        switch (requestCode) {
        case 1:
            Log.i("StartUpActivity", "Photo Captured");
             Uri uri = data.getData();
             String imgPath = getRealPathFromURI(uri);
            bitmap = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
            MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(),
                    bitmap, null, null);
            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
            img1.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
      }
}
```

and note that it is more recommended to using final ints as the request code instead of rewriting them everytime they're needed
like :

```
private final int START_CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this may be help you

Follow Below Code step by step and compare with your code to avoid null exception

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
```

**1** **OnActivity Result**

```
  @Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
     if (requestCode == 1)
            onCaptureImageResult(data);
    }
}
```

**2**
**onCaptureImageResult**

```
 public void onCaptureImageResult(Intent data) {
    Bitmap thumbnail = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
    ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    thumbnail.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, bytes);

    Uri tempUri = getImageUri(getApplicationContext(), thumbnail); // call getImageUri

    File finalFile = new File(getRealPathFromURI(tempUri));
    file_path = finalFile.getPath().toString(); // your file path
    imgview.setImageBitmap(thumbnail);
   // this code will get your capture image bitmap}
```

**3** **getImageUri**

```
 public Uri getImageUri(Context inContext, Bitmap inImage) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    inImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes);
    String path = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(inContext.getContentResolver(), inImage, "Title", null);  // your capture image URL code
    return Uri.parse(path);

}
```

Using this code your screen will not remain more on camera state it will finish and image will be load as well you get image URL.

Answer (score -1):

```
Bitmap mBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgPath);
```

pass  Image path which you create from URI.

Answer (score -1):

Probably, your activity is reloaded after camera is finished, but your code is not prepared to such situation.

See [Android startCamera gives me null Intent and ... does it destroy my global variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20424909/android-startcamera-gives-me-null-intent-and-does-it-destroy-my-global-varia).

Answer (score -1):

I think onActivity is called but it doesn't go into the if condition

Check only for null in if condition:

```
 if (data != null )
    switch (requestCode) {
    case 1:
        Log.i("StartUpActivity", "Photo Captured");
         Uri uri = data.getData();
         String imgPath = getRealPathFromURI(uri);
        bitmap = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
        MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(),
                bitmap, null, null);
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
        img1.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

From where you are calling startActivityForResult(intent, 1),
and where you Overriding onActivityResult() ?

I mean if you call startActivityForResult() from Frgment then you should override onActivityResult() in fragment it self, same applies to Activity also.