# Uri is null while displaying image taken from camera

Tags: android, android-camera, android-image, android-bitmap

Hi I need to take a picture from camera and display it on screen.

But I am getting Uri as null.

I need to get the file absolute path.

My code:

```
mintent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
mintent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,
             MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI.toString());
startActivityForResult(mintent, 1);


@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if ((data != null && !data.toString().equalsIgnoreCase("Intent {  }"))
            || requestCode == 1)
        switch (requestCode) {
        case 1:
            try {
                 Uri imageFileUri = data.getData();

                 Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
img2.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
}
}
```

Please help..

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is here:

```
mintent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
mintent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,
             MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI.toString());
```

You are not passing the URI where you want the file to reside.  Instead you are passing a URI of a folder.  You should instead pass the URI where you want the file to go.  Here's an example from a project I did a few months ago:

```
File lastSavedFile;

/**
 * IMPORTANT: this must be a directory readable by multiple apps (not private storage)
 * @return
 */
@SuppressLint("SimpleDateFormat")
private File getTempFile() {
    // Create an image file name
    String timeStamp =  new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
    String imageFileName = "barfile_" + timeStamp + ".jpg";

    return new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), imageFileName);
}

/**
 * Called when we want to take a picture
 * 
 * @param position
 */
private void launchTakePictureIntent(int position)
{
    Intent i=new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

    lastSavedFile = getTempFile();
    i.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(lastSavedFile));
    startActivityForResult(i, position);
}

/**
 * Returns from the camera intent, hopefully with a picture
 */
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int position, int resultCode, Intent intent) {

    super.onActivityResult(position, resultCode, intent);

    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        Uri imageUri = Uri.fromFile(lastSavedFile);
        Bitmap fullBitmap;
        try {
            fullBitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), imageUri);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, e.toString(), e);
            return;
        }
        ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code I use to get the Uri of the picture.

```
  private Bitmap photo;
  private File pic;
  private Uri uri;

  protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == 1) {
      photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");

      try {
        File root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        if (root.canWrite()) {
          pic = new File(root, "pic.png");
          FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(pic);

          photo.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 100, out);

          out.flush();
          out.close();
        }
      } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("BROKEN", "Could not write file " + e.getMessage());
      }

      // This is the uri you are looking for.
      uri = Uri.fromFile(pic);
    }
  }
```

PS: Don't forget to accept an answer in the previous question you asked: [onActivityResult is not calling after taking camera picture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20845034/onactivityresult-is-not-calling-after-taking-camera-picture/20845322#20845322) if you don't want to have a low reputation.