# ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE - onActivityResult not called

Tags: android

I am calling camera:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(new File(mImagesFolder, TEMP_PHOTO_FILENAME)));
startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE_CAMERA);
```

The camera window shows, a photo is taken and everything looks OK, but in fact `onActivityResult` is not called at all in my activity! I have put a log output between 
`public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {` and `super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);` so I know for sure.
Instead, onCreate() and onResume() are called.
This happens on LG E975 device only.

How can I make it work?

Comment: I have answered this question before
take a look:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/30266776/1531683

Comment: I think it would be helpful for people who will face this question @yar

Comment: That's right, people will see your comment and go to the link.

Answer (score 4):

I was using `android:launchMode="singleInstance"` in my activity in manifest.xml. 
Removed it and it started working again. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks, but I have no way of verifying it now ;)

Answer (score 1):

I was stuck on this issue too. Check if you have `android:noHistory="true"` in your AndroidManifest.xml file. 
Removing that property from the AndroidManifest.xml did the trick for me.